# Is it possible to overload abstract methods in an abstract Java class, but implement only one of the overloaded methods in subclass?

Tags: java, overloading, abstract-class

I have an abstract class (showing only the relevant parts) with two overloaded methods.

```
abstract public class Component {
    ...
    abstract protected void createPhysics();
    abstract protected void createPhysics(Comp1D[] comp1DS);
    ...
}
```

In the subclasses which extend this abstract class I only want to use either the one with arguments or the one without, but never both of them. For example

```
public class Comp1D extends Component{
    ...
    protected void createPhysics(Comp1D[] comp1Ds){
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Comp3D extends Component{
    ...
    protected void createPhysics(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course this won't compile this way since the other createPhysics method is not implemented in the subclass. My quick and dirty solution would be to implement both methods in subclasses, but the unused method would have empty body.

Is there a more elegant way to solve it in Java 8?

Comment: No, there is not. And on a syntactical level, it would not make sense either. If one has a `Component`, one could call both methods. How should one know which one is implemented and which one isn't?

Comment: @martin It is not a good design, but if you still insist to have it working in similar way just don't mark methods as abstract in Component and they will be just empty, in the child classes you could override whatever method you want.  Still don't see the purpose but just saying ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With abstract methods, there is not. And on a syntactical level, it would not be sound either. If one has a `Component`, one can call both methods. How should one know which one is implemented and which one is not?

One could define both method in the abstract class and let them throw, for example, an `UnsupportedOperationException`, thus forcing sublcasses to override (at least one of) those methods if they wish to not throw such an exception. This, however, seems like a workaround for another problem.

I would suggest re-evaluating the overall architecture of that section and find another solution to the problem. For example, maybe two separated classes and handler for those classes would yield a cleaner architecture.

Comment: I have "solved" this problem, by declaring a static Comp1D[] array in Comp1D class, which is set after all 1D components have been initialized. This way every 1D component has access to any other 1D component's properties, and there is no need to give this array as an argument of createPhysics. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: How do you populate this array? Is `Comp1D` a multiton? If one stores all `Comp1D`-objects ever created in this array and users can generate new `Comp1D`-objects, this would be the java-equialten of a memory leak since the stored `Comp1D`-objects cannot be garbage-collected as long as they are stored in the  static array.

Comment: I think it is a multiton (sorry, I'm not a programmer, I just read the definition of multiton on Wikipedia). First, the `Comp1D` objects are created (all of them), then the `comp1Ds` array is set with a setter. After this point, the users should not generate any new `Comp1D` objects. It is possible to create new ones after this, but in the whole framework, it would be illogical to create new ones, after the first 'batch' is created.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, why do you want to use an Abstract class here. What if you plan to use an interface, with default implementations. You can implement the interface and override only the required method

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using abstract class is when you want to define common method signatures in the class and force sub-classes to provide implementation for such methods. From this point of view the way you are trying to implement abstract class doesn't make much sense.

You can also use abstract class to define a base type to support  O-O features like polymorphism and inheritance and i think this is what are you trying to do .
If this is the case i suggest to declare an abstract class without abstract methods or declare an interface with default implementation for both methods and then you can override in  implementation classes.

Comment: I wanted to use abstract class because all of the subclasses have to have these same methods, usually with the same argument list. This createPhysics function is my only exception, because the my 1D components contain physics coupled with each other, so they need to access properties of other 1D components. I'm very new to Java (basically I'm forced to use it), I'm using it since monday I guess, so I'm not very familiar with my possibilities. Also I'm a physicist not a software developer, so I'm also not familiar with 'clean' architectures. I'll give a try to this interface stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Turning85 pointed out, such an implementation would not make much sense.

Either you want to give your `successor` classes the flexibility to implement both of the methods according to their own specific needs or you want to take this complexity away from them and implement the whole logic in the abstract class, where you could have something like this:

```
abstract class Component() {

    protected void createDefaultPhysics() {
        //implement
    }

    abstract protected void createPhysics(Comp1D[] comp1DS);

}
```

and your concrete classes:

```
public class Comp1D extends Component{

      protected void createPhysics(Comp1D[] comp1Ds){
           if(comp1Ds == null) {
                createDefaultPhysics();
           }
      }
}
```